BuildRowsetFromJSON returns null when parsing a hierarchical JSON string sourced from a DE
Below is the sample JSON and the AMPScript to extract the necessary fields from the JSON
{
"_logLevel": "info",
"msg": "attempting to send email to sendgrid",
"awsRegion": "ap-southeast-2",
"functionName": "processNotifications-prod",
"functionVersion": "$LATEST",
"functionMemorySize": "512",
"environment": "prod",
"email": {
    "to": "david.xxxx@xx.com",
    "from": "business@app.xxx.com",
    "replyTo": "business@xxx.com",
    "templateId": "d-06b21ede68a2495ab8f48b4ef5eb0e90",
    "dynamicTemplateData": {
        "user": {
            "id": "0dd9fd9e-79a7-4feb-b794-1152fa179737",
            "firstName": "FirstName",
            "middleName": "",
            "lastName": "Lastname",
            "addressStructured": {
                "unitType": "House",
                "streetName": "Suburb",
                "streetType": "Road",
                "premise": null,
                "streetNumber": "4",
                "unitNumber": "4",
                "block": null,
                "floor": null
            },
            "address": "House 4 4 My Road",
            "city": "Dublin",
            "postCode": "D15N40T",
            "state": "Dublin",
            "email": "david.xxxx@xxx.com",
            "country": "Ireland",
            "countryCode": "IE",
            "countryAreaCode": "+353",
            "dateOfBirth": "01/01/1981",
            "mobile": "+353812390316",
            "fromCurrency": "AUD",
            "toCurrency": "USD",
            "transferRange": "0 - 500,000",
            "createdAt": "2024-10-31T17:06:06.000Z",
            "idVerified": true,
            "roleName": "User",
            "marketingAgreement": true,
            "ofxUserAgreement": true,
            "devices": [
                "apns-116b3943-4ae9-4bba-aff3-c4ca33f948ca"
            ]
        },
        "company": {
            "CompanyId": "4e710f61-5574-460f-a26e-5f153036b5b0",
            "Name": "1stName LastName"
        },
        "payload": {
            "reference": "Transfer NCP test funding",
            "amount": 4.62,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "userName": "1stName LastName",
            "creditedBy": "Jason Xxxxx"
        }
    }
},
"_tags": []

}
%%[
  /*--- assign JSON input---*/
  SET @json = AttributeValue("JSON_Data")
  
  /* SET @json = CONCAT('[',@json,']') */
  OutputLine(v(@json))
  
  /* get the transactional data */
  var  @UsernameX, @referenceX, @amountX, @FromCurrencyX, @creditedByX
  
  /* Decompose the payload data into individual attributes */
   
  SET @ToCurrencyX = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@json,'$.email.dynamicTemplateData.user.toCurrency',1)
  OutputLine(v(@ToCurrencyX))
  SET @ContactGUID = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@json,'$.email.dynamicTemplateData.user.id',1)
  OutputLine(v(@ContactGUID))
  SET @AccountGUID = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@json,'$.email.dynamicTemplateData.company.CompanyId',1)
  OutputLine(v(@AccountGUID))

 
  /* SET @payload = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@json,'$.email',1) */
  
  /* set @rows = BuildRowsetFromJson(@json, '$.[*]', 1) */
  /* OutputLine(v(@rows)) */
  /* set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) */
  /* OutputLine(v(@rowcount)) */
  
  /* set @payload = field(row(@rows,1),"payload") */
  
  SET @payload = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@json,'$.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload',1) 
  OutputLine(v(@payload))
  
  /* SET @payload = CONCAT('[',@payload,']') */
  /* SET @payloadRS = BuildRowsetFromJSON(@payload,'$.[*]',1) */
  /* SET @payloadRowCount = RowCount(@payloadRS) */
  /* OutputLine(v(@payloadRowCount)) *
  /* SET @Row = Row(@payloadRS,1) */
  /* SET @UsernameX = Field(@Row,"Username") */
  /* SET @referenceX = Field(@Row,"Reference") */
  /* SET @amountX = Field(@Row,"amount") */
  /* SET @FromCurrencyX = Field(@Row,"currency") */
  /* SET @creditedByX = Field(@Row,"creditedBy") */

 

]%%

The commented code in the AMPScript are the various attempts to try different options.
Objective is to get subset of the values under the $.email, $.email.dynamicTemplateData.user and $.email.dynamicTemplateData.company nodes and all of the attribute values from the $.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload and I have attempted variations (some commented) in the function call but have not been successful with the responses.
The JSON has no arrays and is uploaded to a DE Text column. The DE is the entry source to test the templated EMail and the AMPScript is a content block referenced inside the email.
I have used the same JSON with and without escape char in different rows in the DE. But the results were the same
I have also tried wrapping the json between [ .. ] but no success (code commented above)
OutputLine(v(@json)) does display the full JSON value as below.

{ "_logLevel": "info", "msg": "attempting to send email to sendgrid", "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-2", "functionName": "processNotifications-prod", "functionVersion": "$LATEST", "functionMemorySize": "512", "environment": "prod", "email": { "to": "david.byrne@xx.com", "from": "business@app.xxx.com", "replyTo": "business@xxx.com", "templateId": "d-06b21ede68a2495ab8f48b4ef5eb0e90", "dynamicTemplateData": { "user": { "id": "0dd9fd9e-79a7-4feb-b794-1152fa179737", "firstName": "FirstName", "middleName": "", "lastName": "Lastname", "addressStructured": { "unitType": "House", "streetName": "Suburb", "streetType": "Road", "premise": null, "streetNumber": "4", "unitNumber": "4", "block": null, "floor": null }, "address": "House 4 4 My Road", "city": "Dublin", "postCode": "D15N40T", "state": "Dublin", "email": "david.byrne@ukforex.com", "country": "Ireland", "countryCode": "IE", "countryAreaCode": "+353", "dateOfBirth": "01/01/1981", "mobile": "+353812390316", "fromCurrency": "AUD", "toCurrency": "USD", "transferRange": "0 - 500,000", "createdAt": "2024-10-31T17:06:06.000Z", "idVerified": true, "roleName": "User", "marketingAgreement": true, "ofxUserAgreement": true, "devices": [ "apns-116b3943-4ae9-4bba-aff3-c4ca33f948ca" ] }, "company": { "CompanyId": "4e710f61-5574-460f-a26e-5f153036b5b0", "Name": "1stName LastName" }, "payload": { "reference": "Transfer NCP test funding", "amount": 4.62, "currency": "EUR", "userName": "1stName LastName", "creditedBy": "Jason Xxxxx" } } }, "_tags": [] }


Can I use the BuildRowsetFromJSON function to traverse nodes and return the value under the node? In the code above, it does not work for ToCurrency, ContactGUID, etc.
Can I use the function to return the node sub-structure as a string (e.g. $.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload) and then execute the function over the result to use the Field function to extract the child items?

Update
This is how it is stored in the DE

Thanks.
Yes, I have tested the SSJS option also.
<script runat='server'>
  // Load the core library
  Platform.Load('Core', '1.1.5');

  var jsonDE = Platform.Variable.GetValue('@json');

  // parse JSON response
  var jsonParsed = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonDE);


  Variable.SetValue("@ToCurrencyX", jsonParsed.email.dynamicTemplateData.user.toCurrency);
  Variable.SetValue("@FromCurrencyX", jsonParsed.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload.currency);
  Variable.SetValue("@referenceX", jsonParsed.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload.reference);
  Variable.SetValue("@amountX", jsonParsed.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload.amount);
  Variable.SetValue("@UsernameX", jsonParsed.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload.userName);
  Variable.SetValue("@creditedByX", jsonParsed.email.dynamicTemplateData.payload.creditedBy);
  Variable.SetValue("@AccountGUID", jsonParsed.email.dynamicTemplateData.company.CompanyId);

</script>

I couldn't figure out (searched SF docs and Stackexchange posts) how to assign the JSON column from DE which is the entry source for the journey within the SSJS script. The @json is set up in ane AMPScript block that precedes the SSJS block

I don't know how many times I've thrown in the towel on BuildRowsetFromJSON.  It's so much easier just to use SSJS:
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">

set @jsonStr = '{"_logLevel":"info","msg":"attempting to send email to sendgrid","awsRegion":"ap-southeast-2","functionName":"processNotifications-prod","functionVersion":"$LATEST","functionMemorySize":"512","environment":"prod","email":{"to":"david.byrne@xx.com","from":"business@app.xxx.com","replyTo":"business@xxx.com","templateId":"d-06b21ede68a2495ab8f48b4ef5eb0e90","dynamicTemplateData":{"user":{"id":"0dd9fd9e-79a7-4feb-b794-1152fa179737","firstName":"FirstName","middleName":"","lastName":"Lastname","addressStructured":{"unitType":"House","streetName":"Suburb","streetType":"Road","premise":null,"streetNumber":"4","unitNumber":"4","block":null,"floor":null},"address":"House 4 4 My Road","city":"Dublin","postCode":"D15N40T","state":"Dublin","email":"david.byrne@example.com","country":"Ireland","countryCode":"IE","countryAreaCode":"+353","dateOfBirth":"01/01/1981","mobile":"+353812390316","fromCurrency":"AUD","toCurrency":"USD","transferRange":"0 - 500,000","createdAt":"2024-10-31T17:06:06.000Z","idVerified":true,"roleName":"User","marketingAgreement":true,"ofxUserAgreement":true,"devices":["apns-116b3943-4ae9-4bba-aff3-c4ca33f948ca"]},"company":{"CompanyId":"4e710f61-5574-460f-a26e-5f153036b5b0","Name":"1stName LastName"},"payload":{"reference":"Transfer NCP test funding","amount":4.62,"currency":"EUR","userName":"1stName LastName","creditedBy":"Jason Xxxxx"}}},"_tags":[]}'

</script>
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
 Platform.Load("core","1");
 try {
 
  var jsonStr = Variable.GetValue("jsonStr")
  var json = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonStr); 
  var email = json.email.dynamicTemplateData.user.email;
  Write("email: " + email)

 } catch (e) {
   Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
 }

</script>

Output:
email: david.byrne@example.com


Thanks. Please see the update to my post. One question, how can you reference the SSJS variable directly in the email template? Is it necessary to use a SetValue (as I have done) to promote as AMPScript  variable and reference in the HTML?

Using var jsonDE = Attribute.GetValue("@json") will get the value from the send context.
